# Не отображается верхняя граница над блоком css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation

```
  .card1-img {
    width: 303px;
    display: block;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-top: 3px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #fff) 1 100%;
  }
```

это картинка и задача сделать градиентный контур.работает и справа и слева но не работает вверху.Подскажите в чем причина.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте

```
border-image-slice: 3 2 3 2;
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Это всё из=за не очень корректной документации на свойство  [border-image-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-width.asp) наверное по причине, того, что это свойство мало кто пользует. Вообщем ваше решение должно быть где-то таким

```css
.card1-img {
  width: 303px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  border-top: 3px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0, #f00) 3 2 0 2 / 3px 2px 0 2px repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1-img">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/g/200/300" alt="cage">
</div>
```